# Why does VC++ introduce the nonstandard keyword: __leave?

Tags: c++, c, exception, visual-c++

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/cpp/try-finally-statement):

> The `__leave` statement is more efficient because it does not cause
> stack unwinding.

To my understanding, that is to say: "Such a common code snippet is dangerous!"

```
struct A
{
    int* p;

    A() : p(new int) {}
    ~A() { delete p; }
};

void f()
{
    __try
    {
        A a;
        ... // Doing somthing
        if (the thing has gone bad) __leave;
        ... // Continue
    }
    __finally
    {}
}
```

**Is it a best practice to totally avoid `__leave` in C++ projects?**

Comment: Actually, I'd consider it _potentially_ evil to use _anything_ not in the ISO C++ standard - it makes porting harder. That may not be a problem in your particular case but some value it.

Comment: `__try`, `__except`, `__leave` and `__finally` are for structured exception handling, a Windows-specific feature that has very particular uses (e.g. catching stack guard pages exceptions, access violations & co.); for "regular" C++ you don't need them.

Comment: The reason nonstandard keywords exist is not *necessarily* so that you can use them to create non-portable programs, but usually to support the standard library.

Comment: The [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xtt5hxz.aspx) in your post says: "Structured exception handling works with Win32 for both C and C++ source files. However, it is not specifically designed for C++. You can ensure that your code is more portable by using C++ exception handling. Also, C++ exception handling is more flexible, in that it can handle exceptions of any type. For C++ programs, it is recommended that you use the C++ exception-handling mechanism (try, catch, and throw statements)."

Comment: In general, useful language features always make somebody unhappy.  The usual complaint is, "That may be helpful, but most people don't know it so I insist it is bad".   I much prefer to think of technology a set of usable tools.  If you don't know about unusual tools,  you will have a harder time solving some problems.  So, your team gets to do a tradeoff analysis:  C++98 (because its is widely known) vs. C++11 (new with lots of extra features.)  [Surely you're not going to argue against C++11 being useful to somebody?  Useful to *you* is another question].  MS vs not MS is the same question.

Comment: @IraBaxter C++11 is standard and portable whilst MS is not. It's not evil because people don't know it, it's undesirable because only few can use it.

Comment: The point is that complaining about `__try` ... `__except` is like complaining that `CreateWindow` is not portable - of course it's not, it's designed to deal with very OS-specific stuff to begin with, and even Microsoft tells you to avoid `__try` in C++ unless you actually *need* to work with SEH. SEH is not a nonstandard alternative to something that is already in the standard, it is used for stuff that the standard accurately *avoids to talk about*, since it cannot be dealt in a platform-agnostic manner.

Comment: @Cramer:  "Only a few can use it"? You clearly underestimate the size of Microsoft's developer base.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I don't understand the part about 'support the standard library'. The standard library doesn't need any support other than from the language it is standard for.

Comment: And so to the question at hand, should you avoid `__leave`? Yes, you should avoid it unless you NEED it. In which case you cannot avoid it and the question is moot.

Comment: @EJP: VC++ uses SEH to implement C++ EH, since this allows it to exploit functionality already provided by the OS. Exactly as `CreateFile` and several other Windows APIs are used to implement `<iostream>`, `CreateHeap` & co. for `malloc`/`new`, and so on. In other words, he's telling you that it's part of the OS-specific functionality over which the CRT is built.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I don't see how that answers my question. Adding a keyword didn't accomplish that. The functionality already existed in the form of APIs.

Comment: @EJP: no, but it's useful for developers who have to work with SEH (including the developers of the CRT), e.g. to catch a stack guard page, catch an access violation, catch a FP exception and whatever; not everything can be done in a platform-independent way, and having some help from the compiler for this stuff is always useful. Also, all these keywords start with two underscores, exactly as prescribed by the standard for implementation-specific stuff, and even Microsoft discourages their use if you don't actually need SEH, so I don't see the point of complaining about it.

Comment: @MatteoItalia You keep answering a different question from the one I'm asking. I asked Dietrich what he meant by 'to support the standard library'. You haven't addressed that in the slightest. This does not constitute 'complaining', it constitutes asking a simple question, which apparently you haven't even bothered to read accurately.

Comment: @EJP: it's widely used inside the CRT (a quick `grep -r __try | wc -l` over the CRT sources shows 171 instances of `__try`) to deal with Windows-specific stuff and build our nice C/C++ library abstraction over it. It could be done using just the SEH Windows functions? Of course, but since `__try` is already there (it's extremely useful to VC++ users when dealing with scenarios described above, as well as in drivers programming) and it's much more convenient than the alternative, they used it. Again, I agree with you that it's not essential for the CRT, but it actually *is* used to support it.

Comment: @MatteoItalia If it was 'already there', it wasn't introduced 'to support the standard library' at all, which is really the answer to the question that I actually asked. Please stick to the point.

Comment: @EJP: There are actually many things in the standard library which cannot be supported by the core language without either special keywords, or having the compiler treat things that look like library facilities as if they were special keywords.  In particular, much of the templates defined in the `<type_traits>` header.

Comment: @EJP: it is *used* to support the standard library, among the other things. As for the exact timeline, honestly I don't know; it was already present in Windows NT 4, Windows 95 and in MS compilers of that era, so I think that, starting with the 32-bit Windows versions (the first to support SEH), they shipped the compiler already with these features and with a CRT using them; after all, it was (mostly) the same compiler they used to build Windows.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Possibly so, but all I am getting on the subject is confusion as to whether or not `__leave`, which is the topic of this question, is one of them. Could you *also* please stick to the point.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Thanks for the information, but, once again, that isn't the question I asked. The question I asked was addressed to Dietrich. Perhaps we should leave it to him to respond.

Comment: @EJP: *"The standard library doesn't need any support other than from the language it is standard for."* -- I was responding to that.  Could you please try to remember the point you originally made?

Comment: @EJP: Matteo Italia has answered your question to my satisfaction.

Comment: I hardly don't see this type of warning, if it's a gcc extension, BTW

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version of the article titled ["try-finally statement (C)"](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/c-language/try-finally-statement-c) at the time of this answer said:

> For C++ programs, C++ exception handling should be used instead of [structured exception handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp). For more information, see Exception Handling in the C++ Language Reference.

Edit:
Also, it's usually good to refrain from compiler specific features.

Comment: Also: *Although Windows and Visual C++ support structured exception handling (SEH), we recommend that you use ISO-standard C++ exception handling because it makes code more portable and flexible. Nevertheless, in existing code or for particular kinds of programs, you still might have to use SEH.* (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swezty51.aspx)

Comment: While generally true, I disagree with this outright notion of refraining from compiler-specific features. By and large this is what we should aim for. But foregoing SEH and VEH, ignoring its use cases, based on zealotry helps no one. I find it fascinating how very often people speak out against compiler-specific stuff and for standards-compliance, then happily go on to use all sorts of compiler-specific stuff in "their" compiler of choice and standards-violating headers/libraries all the same.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.  `__try`/`__finally` are built for Win32 [structured exception handling (SEH)](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp), which is not *quite* the same as C++ exception handling.  If you're writing a Win32 application, you *must* use Win32 SEH. If not, I'd stick with C++ exception handling.